# How can I get values of http.get?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I think I am confusing about the scope of JavaScript.  When I tried following code (using Node.js), I could not get any output from second "*console.log()*".  In this program, I think *value variable* should have some value after executing *http.get()* since *value variable* is in global scope.  But returned value is against my anticipation.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: "www.example.com",
    path: "/index.html",
    port: 80
};

var value = "";
var ret = http.get(options, function(res) {
                       res.on("data", function(chunk) {
                                  value += chunk;
                              });
                       res.on("end", function(chunk) {
                                  console.log(value); // have some value...
                              })
                   });
console.log(value); // don't have any value...why?
```

I would like to know what is going on.  Thanks in advance!

(following text is a supplement)

Thanks a lot to three guys who gave me answer!  I delayed the execution of second *console.log()* using setTimeout as follows.  But I still have the same problem.  I wonder how I can get value.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: "www.example.com",
    path: "/index.html",
    port: 80
};

var value = "";
var ret = http.get(options, function(res) {
                       res.on("data", function(chunk) {
                                  value += chunk;
                              });
                       res.on("end", function(chunk) {
                                  console.log("first: " + value); // have some value...
                              })
                   });
setTimeout(function() {
               console.log("second: " + value); // don't have any value...why?
           }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're defining a callback function on the `http.get`, and then you're executing through, so executing the final `console.log`, BEFORE `value` is set.  In the meantime, I don't know if your callback is actually getting called.  Try adding some additional `console.log` statements to make sure your flow of execution is what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is asynchronous callbacks.

What happens is the `function(res) {...}` is called and when `http.get` is *finished* and there it will add values to `value`. However, after `http.get` it will log `value` when it's not been filled yet.

So basically,

1. `http.get` is called
2. `console.log` is called
3. `http.get` is finished, the `function(res) {...}` is called

Answer (score 1):

An http request is asynchronous. The second console.log() (where the variable `value` has no value) is actually called before the request returns, and therefore, it has the same value it was initialized with.